# External file sheet with safari

Tags: html, css, safari, media-queries

I have been coding and running my application in IE, i have downloaded Safari to test to see if my application works with that browser and when i load up my home screen the CSS isnt getting called.

I have developed my program using media screen and having 2 different style sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1600px)" type="text/css" href="../../Style/MinWidth1600StyleSheet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1280px)" type="text/css" href="../../Style/MaxWidth1280StyleSheet.css" />
```

I have used absolute positioning but will be creating more style sheets when coming to the end of my application as I feel this is my way of comfortably coding.

Does anyone know the reason for Safari not calling any of my style sheets?

Comment: ...maximize the window and reload, then make it very small and reload again. Maybe safari window is in the gat between your media queries, so it's (properly) loading none of them. Try and tell us what happend.

Comment: @miguel-svq I have ran my program and the Welcome page and Login page works ok and loads correctly in the 1600 css stylesheet. When I go from the Welcome page to the dashboard the screen doesn't find a css, so I resized the safari window and it found the 1600 stylesheet. But then weirdly I put the window back to fit my screen and it still found it? So when it loads the page it doesnt find it but when i resize and but it back to fit my screen it does?

Comment: First step is to avoid that gap between css or your application/page will not show any css on many browsers on many screens. If then there is still some kind of issue check the specific page to verify what html is being received in the browser, etc, etc... I'm quite sure that your problem will go away if you avoid that gap.

Comment: @miguel-svq What resolution is the gap at?

Comment: From 1280px to 1600px (size, not resolution) Read your media queries, its quite obvious what they are doing. Make a google search about media queries and you'll get a lot of helpfull tutorials that could help you to understand what is going on with those min, max, widths...

Comment: @miguel-svq The screen resolutions go from width 1280 then the next one is width 1600 so I don't have a gap?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1600px)" type="text/css" href="../../Style/MinWidth1600StyleSheet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1280px)" type="text/css" href="../../Style/MaxWidth1280StyleSheet.css" />
```

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

../../Style/MinWidth1600StyleSheet.css will be loaded IF min-width: 1600px : the viewport is 1600px width, or wider.

../../Style/MaxWidth1280StyleSheet.css will be loaded IF max-width: 1280px : the viewport if 1280px width, or narrower.

There is no css for displays wider than 1280px and narrower than 1600px. Please check documentation about CSS media queries.

Comment: I found this website called http://responsivepx.com/ which finds where my application needs its queries mine brakes between width 1264 to width 1582 but when i add a query in for that it still does not hit the query ?

Comment: Seems you have not even read the linked doc. Did you? Change the 'sizes' as needed so you have no gap between them. Don't you see it?

Comment: i have read the artical and i can see im missing resolution but when i add the media query `<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1281px) and (max-width:1599px)" type="text/css" href="../Style/StyleSheet1.css"/>` into my code it still doesn't find it

Comment: _Change the 'sizes' as needed_ I said nothing about adding a new stylesheet.